# Redondear de decenas a centenas en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una lista de precios que necesito redondear, en este caso los valores de las decenas no me sirven.

Por ejemplo:

28320 > 28300

31860 > 31900

57820 > 57800

38940 > 38900

Actualmente lo hago con la función de Excel `REDONDEAR(value,-2)`
pero no logro obtener el mismo resultado con las funciones
`Math.round`, `Math.ceil` o `toFixed()` de JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución simple es:

- Dividir el número por 100 (*convertir las unidades y decenas en decimales*)
- Aplicar `Math.round` para redondear según corresponda (*para arriba o abajo*)
- Multiplicar el resultado por 100.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function redondear(num) {
  return Math.round(num / 100) * 100;
}

let numeros = [28320, 31860, 57820, 38940];
numeros.map(n => console.log(n + ' > ' + redondear(n)));
```

---

Otra opción sería restarle [el *"resto"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) de dividirlo en 100.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function redondear(num) {
  return num - (num % 100);
}
let numeros = [28320, 31860, 57820, 38940];
numeros.map(n => console.log(n + ' > ' + redondear(n)));
```

---

## Un paso mas allá

Si quisieras utilizar un "indice" para indicar si redondear sobre los decimales o la parte entera, podrías hacerlo así:

- Si el **indice es mayor a cero**, significa que el redondeo es sobre los decimales, por lo que deberíamos, primero multiplicar, redondear y dividir
- Si el **indice es menor a cero**, significa que el redondeo es sobre la parte entera, por lo que deberíamos, primero dividir, redondear y multiplicar

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function redondear(num, exp) {
  let pow = Math.pow(10, Math.abs(exp));
  return exp > 0 ?
    Math.round(num * pow) / pow :
    Math.round(num / pow) * pow;
}

let numeros = [28320.538, 31860.426, 57820.613, 38940.297];
numeros.map(n => console.log(n + ' > ' + redondear(n, -2)));
numeros.map(n => console.log(n + ' > ' + redondear(n, 2)));
```